# Instance of the timer control? In window forms?

Tags: winforms

In window forms, when i am creating timer control dynamically, how can i differentiate the object of the timer control, the timer controls are n number... it is deisde at runt time. Help me thank you..

Answer (score 1):

You simply create a instance field of type Dictionary on your main form, you can also use the Tag property of the timer:

```
class MainForm(Form)
{

    Dictionary<string, Timer> timers;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
        timers = new Dictionary<string, Timer>();
    }    


    public Timer AddTimer( string name, int interval, bool enabled, int id)
    {
          Timer t = new Timer();
          t.Interval = interval;
          t.Enabled = enabled;
          t.Tag = id;
          t.Ticks += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);
          timers.add(name, t);

          return t;
    } 

    public Timer GetTimer(string name)
    {
        if (timers.ContainsKey(name))
        {
              return timers[name];
        }
        else
        {
              return null;
        }
    } 

       private static void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject,
                                            EventArgs myEventArgs) {
             Timer sourceTimer = myObject as Timer;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for response Mr. Icfseth i will check and let you know

Comment: Mr. Icfseth when i am writing the... Timer t = new Timer();        t.Name = name; i am getting error t.Name there is no such a property

Answer (score 0):

It is better to replace timer control with threads. Unlimited timer controls will require more resources than threads.

If continue with timer controls, better to store the control names of each timer created in an array and you could select the one you want by searching the array.

Comment: Hi vijaykumar, you told me to use thread but it is not like timer na i want for ever second one i wnat to fetch the data, is it possible by using thread?